# Eclipse like Tasklist in Intellij idea

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

Is there any tool in intellij idea 12 which is similar to eclipse task list - mylyn.?
I am using intellij-idea 12 ultimate edition.

Comment: What does a tasklist look like and how does it function? can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this feature?

[image]

You can config it in Preferences -> Tasks.

Comment: Cant see the image. Does it come from the Task Management plugin?

Comment: Yes.But how to I crate a task? I dont have JIRA or other servers. I want to store those task in localhost.